# No cranking Chevy Malibu 2008

Tags: starting, chevrolet, ignition, malibu, no-crank-no-start

I have a 2008 Chevy Malibu four cylinder 2.4 L the battery tested good brand-new starter but I am still getting a no start no crank. I have full power in the car but when I turn the key everything dims until I release the key. I have tried the neutral safety switch trick I tried the antitheft trick of turning the key to accessory for a while and then off and then trying to start my connections all look good I've checked all my fuses and my relays. He problem began when I replaced my battery due to corrosion. Ever since then I've had a no start no crank. I'm fairly handy with cars but this one has me scratching my head. The only thing I can think would be ignition switch or possibly corroded positive cable from the inside that I can't see. Any additional ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I can not comment yet so I have to ask this as an answer.
When you turn ignition on (do not try and crank) does your security light turn out, flash or stay solid? Its a little padlock symbol in cluster. The biggest no crank things I run into on these would be the immobilizer being active and faulty ecm's no longer sending crank signal. Considering all you did was change battery tho I would look at and rule out bad connections and the immobilizer getting reset/corrupted first.

Comment: See if you can jump the starter directly with the key turned to the on position. You'd have to jump the contacts from the main power to the relay on the starter solenoid. If lights are dimming when you turn the key, either the power isn't getting to the starter or the starter isn't working (taking juice but not spinning).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct about the bad positive cable (or the negative cable).  There is obviously a bad connection that is causing a voltage drop when attempting to draw a large current,  which causes the lights to dim.

The connection between the cable and battery terminal connector on either the positive or negative cable may be corroded.  It may even be as simple as the connector needs cleaning where it touches the battery terminals.

If there is no fault at the battery terminals, also check the other end of the cables.